# Aplicativo rejeitado pela Apple erro de IPv6

Tags: ios, ionic, apple, ipv6

Desenvolvi um aplicativo híbrido usando Ionic e ao enviar para a revisão da Apple Store ele foi rejeitado, obtive a seguinte mensagem de erro:

> We discovered one or more bugs in your app when reviewed on iPad and
>   iPhone running iOS 9.3.5 on Wi-Fi connected to an IPv6 network.
>
> Specifically, after we launched your app, an error message appeared.
>
> The steps to reproduce are:
>
> 1. Launch app
> 2. Observe error message

Eles dizem que é necessário suporte a IPv6, porém só dizem isso, sem dar mais nenhuma informação útil. Não tenho como testar o app numa rede IPv6 no momento. Já vi como faz para ligar uma no mac, porem não tenho um adaptador para cabo de rede, uso apenas o WiFi.

Pesquisei bastante e vi várias respostas dizendo ser erro no modo em que as requisições são feitas às API's/servidores ou ainda erro de configuração no próprio servidor/API.

Não sei como resolver isso, o app roda normalmente em condições normais (entenda-se: num iphone em rede IPv4) sem problema algum, tudo perfeito.

Comment: Cara ipv6 não é mais usado em nenhum aparelho.

Comment: @sysWOW32 , IPv6 é a nova geração do protocolo de internet que vai substituir o IPv4. Ele não é usado em massa ainda, mas será num futuro breve, tanto que a Apple tornou **obrigatório** que os apps funcionem em redes IPv6, conforme essa notícia https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=05042016a e conforme a própria documentação https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010220-CH213-SW1

Comment: IPV6 nunca mais será usado em nenhum dispositivo por ser um endereçamento muito extenso. Esse futuro que você aguarda já passou faz tempo!

Comment: Tanto que se voce for nas propriedades de conexão vai estar ipv6 sem acesso a internet. Os provedores deixaram de trabalhar com isso!

Comment: @sysWOW32 acho que você está confundindo "alguma coisinha". Sugiro uma pesquisada melhor no assunto.

Comment: Não entendi o downvote e nem o motivo do voto de fechamento, a pergunta não tem nada haver com opinião, esse problema é comum no ionic com o iOS, acho uma pergunta bem valida.

Comment: Como assim ipv6 não é mai usado? Cadê a fonte dessa afirmação? o que ando lendo nos maiores portais de tecnologia é justamente o contrário.

Comment: Saiu este [artigo](http://blog.ionic.io/apples-switch-to-ipv6-what-it-means-for-your-app/) no blog do Ionic dai eu lembre desta pergunta. Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema!

O app não tinha problemas, visto que segui todas as [referências](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010220-CH213-SW1) da apple para suporte a IPv6. A questão era que o meu servidor, onde o app fazia as requisições, não estava configurado para suportar o IPv6, portanto dava o bendito erro!
Demorou pra cair a ficha, mas depois de tanto pesquisar na net deu certo.

Então, se alguém tiver o mesmo problema, não se esqueça de seguir os padrões da apple e, principalmente, **conferir se o servidor suporta IPv6**. Se for hospedagem externa, como foi meu caso, basta entrar em contato com a equipe da sua hospedagem para ver como habilitar o suporte ao IPv6.

Obrigado a todos que deram dicas aí!

Comment: você estava usando um webview com login? quais configurações extamente você alterou para funcionar, consegue dar mais detalhes?

Answer (score -1):

Conforme esta resposta https://stackoverflow.com/a/37896631/1518921 você pode resolver no cordova usando este plugin [cordova-HTTP](https://github.com/wymsee/cordova-HTTP), que esta usando [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) v3.1.0

E pode fazer algo como:

```
// usa AFNetworking se for iOS device
if ($window.cordova && ionic.Platform.isIOS()) {
    // $window.CordovaHttpPlugin.get
    // $window.CordovaHttpPlugin.post
    // ou
    // cordovaHTTP.get
    // cordovaHTTP.post
} else {
    // $http.get
    // $http.post
}
```

### Como testar se estou usando IPV6

Este parece ser o mesmo problema https://stackoverflow.com/a/38500762/1518921

De acordo [com a politica da Apple](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=08282015a), sua aplicação irá precisar de suporte para o IPV6

Para testar se a sua aplicação suporta IPV6 ou não use isto [Supporting IPv6 DNS64/NAT64 Networks](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010220-CH213-SW1)

Para fazer esta checagem será nacessário seguir os passos indicados na página da Apple.

Para configurar o IPV6 na sua rede Local Wi-Fi você precisará usar o seu Mac:

1) Conecte o seu Mac em outra rede que **não seja Wi-Gi** usando cabo de rede por exemplo.

[image]

2) Vá até **System Preferences** no Dock, LaunchPad, ou no menu.

[image]

3) Aperte a tecla <kbd>Option</kbd> e clique em **Sharing**. Não solte o botão <kbd>Option</kbd>

[image]

4) Selecione Internet Sharing na lista de serviços *sharing services*.

5) Solte o botão <kbd>Option</kbd>

6) Selecione o checkbox *Create NAT64 Network*.

7) Escolha a interface de internet que irá prover a conexão com a Internet, algo como **Thunderbolt Ethernet** ou somente **Ethernet**.

8) Selecione o checkbox Wi-Fi.

[image]

9) Clique em **Wi-Fi Options** e configure as opções **name** e **security** da sua rede.

10) Selecione o checkbox **Internet Sharing** e hablite a sua conexão local.

11) Quando aparecer uma janela para confirmar se você quer compartilhar clique em Start

[image]

12) Agora o seu Mac irá funcionar como um hotspot e usará **IPv6 NAT64**

[image]

---

Agora conecte o seu iPhone no seu Mac e teste se sua aplicação funciona como esperado.

Um detalhe, não se esqueça de adicionar os seguintes frameworks:

1) **WebKit**

2) **CFNetwork**

[image]

Comment: Quem deu o downvote poderia justificar para que eu possa tentar melhorar a resposta? Se o motivo do downvote for a pergunta por favor explique o que tem de errado nela, pois até aonde entendo isto é um problema normal com dispositivos iOS.

Comment: obrigado pela resposta, mas como eu disse na pergunta, "Não tenho como testar o app numa rede IPv6 no momento.Já vi como faz para ligar uma no mac, porem não tenho um adaptador para cabo de rede, uso apenas o WiFi."

entretanto, não tinha encontrado isso sobre o cordova-http, foi útil. Vou fazer os testes aqui e volto para dizer se funcionou!

Comment: @VictorAugustoLopes blz, só coloquei o teste para evitar que você precise fazer o envio sem ter certeza se o software está OK, é um adicional. Espero que o plugin para cordova funcione :)